# How to open a userform through a custom excel ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to open a userform through a custom excel ribbon.  When I click the button in the ribbon it begins initializing and on the workbooks.open function it sends the code to the queryclose sub. The show userform code is below:

```
Sub RemoveFixture_onAction(control As IRibbonControl)
    SelectedCompType = Fixture
    Set EditComp = New ufUpdateComp
        With EditComp
            .Top = Application.Top + 125
            .Left = Application.Left + 25
            .Show
        End With
End Sub
```

When the code begins the userform_Initialize code it ends up moving to the query_close sub.  The code for that is below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    'If wb Is Nothing Then UserForm_Initialize
    wb.Close False
End Sub
```

As seen above, in the commented out section, I tried to return to the initialize sub when the code moved to the queryclose function. It moves to the queryclose sub when it runs the workbooks.open code and it says that the wb is nothing. I have tried opening the workbook separately and then setting the workbook as ActiveWorkbook.  I also tried:
do while wb is nothing
set wb = ActiveWorkbook
loop
This loop ran endlessly until I had to manually cancel it.
It was originally set wb = workbooks.open(Test)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Workbooks.Open Test, , , , , DynoCompPassword, True
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Info")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Info")
    Set wsC = wb.Worksheets("Calipers")
    Set wsF = wb.Worksheets("Fixtures")
    Set wsW = wb.Worksheets("Wheel Sims")
    ws.Visible = True
    wsC.Visible = True
    wsF.Visible = True

btnCreate.Enabled = False
Dim rng As Range

lblLocation.Visible = False
tbLocation.Visible = False
Me.cbOut.AddItem "Sent To"
Me.cbOut.AddItem "Scrapped"
Me.cbOut.AddItem "Returned"
Me.btnCreate.Enabled = True

For Each rngprojectcode In ws.Range("ProjectCode")
    Me.cbProjectCode.AddItem rngprojectcode.Value
Next rngprojectcode

Set ProjCodeDictionary = New Dictionary 'Create the dictionary
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim ProjCodeString As String
Dim AssociatedCodes As ProjectCodeList

If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ProjCodeDictionary.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'Make the .exists method case insensitive in an attempt to avoid duplicate values

    Set AssociatedCodes = New ProjectCodeList 'create the class module which will split up the associated codes into individual values
    i = 1
    While ws.Range("F1").Offset(i, 0) <> ""
        With AssociatedCodes
            .SetCodes = CStr(ws.Range("F1").Offset(i, 0).Value)
            For j = 1 To .NumCodes
                ProjCodeDictionary.Add .ProjCode(j), i 'key, item
            Next j
        End With
        i = i + 1
     Wend

If SelectedCompType = Fixture Then
    Me.lblCompNum.Caption = "Fixture ID"
    Me.btnCreate.Caption = "Update Fixture"
        'Automation Error occurs here
    Me.Caption = "Edit Fixture"
    Me.frChangeFrame.Height = 65
    Me.frChangeFrame.Caption = "Bolt Circle"
    Me.cbPartNum.Text = "FIX"
        For Each rng In wsF.Range("FixtureNum")
        Me.cbPartNum.AddItem rng.Value
        Next rng
    Set tbNumStuds = frChangeFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", , "True")
```

To clarify, the queryclose sub should only be activated when the red box with the X is pressed in the userform.  It is a built in function of the userform.

Comment: So, just checking: you have workbook One, with ribbon commands to open a userform. Userform_Initialize opens workbook Two. Correct?

Comment: You are asking how to open a userform from a custom ribbon or how to set he activeworkbook?  Regarding opening a userform, you want to reference the code that opens the userform (e.g., `application.run "module1.callUF"`), since that is tried and true (you may want some error handling to verify the appropriate workbook is open).  You can just `set wb = activeworkbook` as this will overwrite the last declaration, no issues.

Comment: Putting that code in the form's `Initialize` handler will make the handler run *before* the form is shown. That said, if you want to make that form appear when the user clicks your custom Ribbon command, you're going to need code associated with that Ribbon command, that invokes the `Show` method against an instance of the form.

Comment: I've re-read this post several times, and still can't figure out what the question is and how the code block shown relates to "opening a userform through a custom excel ribbon" in any way, nor why a form needs to get involved, or whether "it sends the code to the queryclose sub" is a problem or if it's expected. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Matthieu, I just added some additional information to the post.  The problem is when I open the userform, it sends me to the queryclose sub during the initialize code.  The only time the queryclose sub should run is when the X button is pressed on the userform.  Please ask for any more information and code that could help diagnose this.

Comment: Mistella, the ribbon is actually an add-in that is always loaded into my excel.  there is only one workbook that is opened and it is opened when the button is clicked in the ribbon, then as the userform initializes, it should open the workbook.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I hope below answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

> *The only time the queryclose sub should run is when the X button is pressed on the userform.*

But that's not how `QueryClose` works. The `UserForm.QueryClose` event is fired whenever the form is about to be closed, and its parameters give you means to cancel it, depending on what prompted it to close.

What you want is to run `wb.Close False` conditionally, when the `CloseMode` parameter value is `vbFormControlMenu` (the X button - see [QueryClose constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/queryclose-constants)):

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        wb.Close False
    End If
End Sub
```

> *I tried to return to the initialize sub when the code [...]*

Don't do this. Event handlers are meant to be invoked by VBA itself, not user code. If you need to invoke logic that you've implemented in an event handler, refactor the code out of the handler and into its own procedure instead:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    DoInitializationStuff
End Sub

Private Sub DoInitializationStuff()
    '...
End Sub
```

Lastly, the `UserForm.Initialize` event is fired well before the form is shown.

```
Set EditComp = New ufUpdateComp ' <~ initialize handler runs before this instruction returns
With EditComp
    .Top = Application.Top + 125
    .Left = Application.Left + 25
    .Show
End With
```

Note that you don't need to declare the local variable if you're only using it in a `With` block - have the block hold the object reference instead:

```
With New ufUpdateComp ' <~ initialize handler runs before this instruction returns
    .Top = Application.Top + 125
    .Left = Application.Left + 25
    .Show
End With
```

If you want `DoInitializationStuff` to run *after* the form is shown, invoke it in the `Activate` event.

Comment: I changed the with statement to open the userform as well as the queryclose to involve the closemode verification.  It seemed to help until I get an automation error: The callee (server [not server application]) is not available and disappeared; all connections are invalid. The call may have executed.  The interesting part about this is if I debug and step through it will work, but if I close excel and reopen it I get the same error.

Comment: Mathieu, I updated the initialize code in the prompt, near the bottom is where it throws the automation error, I am going to try placing in a separate module now.

Comment: @LearningVBA the `Initialize` handler is meant to set default control properties before the form is displayed, not to open a workbook and run 50 lines of automation logic against it. Sure move that code to another module, but more importantly don't invoke it from `UserForm_Initialize`. This is growing into something well beyond the original question though.

Comment: After moving my initialize into a 'DoInitializationStuff' sub and calling out that sub in the Initialize sub it still has the automation error at the same spot.

Comment: Once more: ***don't** invoke it from `UserForm_Initialize`*

Comment: Okay, I think I understand; the initialize function should only be setting up the userform on a basic level and the rest of the code, such as opening workbooks, creating collections and dictionaries, etc should occur after the userform has been initialized.

Comment: Yes. That said the automation error might be elsewhere. But the `Initialize` handler should be simple, trivial code that assigns form and control properties and configures the form just before it's displayed.

Comment: Okay, I will continue to work on it. Thank you Matthieu for all your help!